# Not able to query cross database in Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database

I tried to insert data into another table, in another database, but I get an error:

> Reference to database and/or server name in 'xxx.xxx.xxx' is not supported in this version of SQL Server

I'm getting the same error when trying to select from another database.

My SQL code:

```sql
INSERT INTO xxx.xxx.xxx 
VALUES (xx,'xx', 'xxxx', xx)
```

Comment: In azure sql cross database query is not supported for that you need to create an external datasource and create external table to query

Comment: If you need cross database queries, in an Azure SQL Database, it may well be that you're using the wrong product. Azure SQL Databases are *contained* databases by design; each database is meant to be complete and independent. Perhaps you should be looking at an Azure hosted SQL Server.

Comment: Azure SQL Managed Instance allows cross database natively without the need to create elastic queries (external tables).

Comment: Follow this tutorial https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4550/sql-azure-cross-database-querying/

Comment: @ThomA ok we will think on it to use azure hosted SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure SQL database Cross database quires are not supported You cannot insert records from one database to another database.

**You cannot use DML statements on Cross database in azure SQL.**

- **The only way to insert records is connect to the correct database or switch the database context if you're in SSMS/ADS/ portal Then you can execute your statements.**
- Regarding the cross database quires, you need to use elastic queries like external tables and external data sources suggested by Alberto Morillo

**Sample Code:**

```sql
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password';

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL samplecred2  
WITH IDENTITY = 'username',  
SECRET = 'password';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE RemoteReferenceData
   WITH
      (
         TYPE=RDBMS,
         LOCATION='servername.database.windows.net',
         DATABASE_NAME='db name',
         CREDENTIAL= samplecred
      );

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[tableename]
   (
      Id int,
      Name varchar(20)
   )
   WITH
   (
      DATA_SOURCE = RemoteReferenceData,
      SCHEMA_NAME = 'schemaname',  
      OBJECT_NAME = 'tablename' 
   );
```

Now you can execute quires on the external table which looks similar.

Reference -[Cross-database Query in Azure SQL Database - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/cross-database-query-in-azure-sql-database/ba-p/369126)